# Global array size determined by another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create a global 2-dimensional array who's size would depend on two values entered in another forms textboxes. However, I get an error saying that the values are not static.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 frm = new Form1();
    PictureBox[,] MyArray = new PictureBox[Convert.ToInt32(frm.textbox1.text), Convert.ToInt32(frm.textbox1.text)];
}
```

Since those textboxes are not static (the value in them can be changed), the error is given. I have tried multiple things to bypass this problem; I tried initializing a constant from those textboxes, but it gives the same error, I have also tried resizing the array, but Array.Resize does not work since it is multidimensional and Array.Copy does not work since I need the array to be global

To give you an idea of what I am trying to do, on the first form Form1, the user enters a width and length value. The user then presses confirm, and Form2 opens. The second form Form2 will have an array who's size is determined by the values the user entered. This array will serve to work with a grid also determined by the values entered by the user.

What is the way to bypass the non-static error and create an array with those values?

Comment: Your code should work fine.  What is the **exact** text of the error?

Comment: @Ramhound: There's nothing wrong with that.  Paste `new PictureBox[Convert.ToInt32("42"), Convert.ToInt32("5")]` into LINQPad to see.

Comment: You typed in the values manually. You can't grab user input and use it to initialize an array (the problem lies with `frm.textbox1.text`). What you copied and tested is **not** the same as what the OP posted.

Comment: @SpikeX: You are completely wrong on both counts.   Array sizes an be arbitrary expressions.  The C# compiler doesn't know what `Convert.ToInt32` means; once that's there, it's not a constant.

Comment: @SLaks I can't tell you the exact text of the error since I am using VS2010 in french, however I can translate it roughly; it says the variable or array cannot be initialized because Project.Form2.frm is not static

Comment: Then I guess I was confused with the original question... why not just use `int.Parse`? EDIT: Oh, I didn't even see that he was in a field initializer and not in a method... duh. :/

Comment: @MrRoy: That's because you're in a field initializer.  See my answer.

Comment: @SpikeX: `int.Parse` is roughly equivalent to `Convert.ToInt32`, except that it doesn't handle `null`.

Comment: I will admit I was wrong. I assumed it was because the compiler wasn't able to determine the size of the array it should intialize ( I suppose this is still an accurate statement ). There is nothing wrong with the code besides the location of the code itself. I have stop using Arrays for a great deal of reasons and switch to pure generic collections.

Comment: @Ramhound Ditto, same. I almost never use arrays anymore, since there are only a small number of reasons why you wouldn't use a collection. Probably one of the reasons I prefer collections, too... they're just simpler overall. No messing with size initialization (yuck).

Comment: @Spike - An array is still technically a collection its just not a generic collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you instantiate 'frm' on Form2 you are not referencing the existing form by rather creating a new instance of type Form1.(Which you do not then ".show()")

*Assuming* you are launching form2 from form1 looking something like this:

```
protected void launchForm2()
      {
         Form2 form2 = new Form2();
         form2.Show();
      }

// you need to change that to look like this:

protected void launchForm2()
      {
         Form2 form2 = new Form2();
         form2.Parent = this;
         form2.Show();
      }
```

Then in form2 you need to address the "Parent" like this:

```
//added to declare myArray global to the form.
PictureBox[,] MyArray;

// to make it 'global' to the application you will need to create some manner of "globalApplicationContext" and pass references of that around or use a 'baseForm' that holds a reference... there are (of course) other solutions as well to globalizing it..

      protected void updateArray()
      {
        string textFromForm1 = ((Form1)this.Parent).textBox1.Text;
// remarked out after @Justin's comment...thx.        
//PictureBox[,] MyArray = new PictureBox[Convert.ToInt32(textFromForm1), Convert.ToInt32(textFromForm1)];

MyArray = new PictureBox[Convert.ToInt32(textFromForm1), Convert.ToInt32(textFromForm1)];
      }
```

This will keep your references in order...

Comment: This is very true, but it's a separate issue.

Comment: Also, since he wants a global array, MyArray shouldn't actually be (re)declared inside updateArray

Comment: @Slaks, in the code sample he has posted his reference to Form1 has just been instantiated and has not been shown, therefore he is attempting to access the property through the type and not the instance. (thus the non-static error...) How is this not the problem?

Comment: @Justin, you are correct, I just took that line from his code. Being more concerned about the faulty reference to Form1 than to the array being populated, good catch.

Comment: @Cos: It is his problem.  However, it's not the problem that he asked about in this question.  Now that he solved that problem, this is his current problem.

Comment: @SLaks what do you mean by this other problem?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot reference your instance (including instance fields) in field initializers, since the instance has not been constructed yet.

Move your code to the `Form1` **constructor**.

Comment: It is not possible since textBox1.Text is undefined when the program starts.

Comment: @MrRoy: You also need to show the form.  (Or use an existing instance).  See @Cos' answer.

Comment: If it's not defined when the program starts, it's not going to be defined in a field initializer, either, since those come *before* the constructor.

Comment: your suggestion to simply move his code to the constructor of Form1 won't help either. frm is still not a full instance of the Form1 object. Closes thing to your approach is to move the line that starts "PictureBox" to the click event of the form1 confirm button and replace `frm` with `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Others have pointed to solutions, so this is just a followup. Communication between forms quickly gets very confusing. Anyways, you are placing way too much logic on the forms. Business logic should be separated from your GUI. Look into the Model-View-Controller pattern.